# Apache2 : 2 VirtualHosts 1 ServerName 2 ServerPath

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, virtualhost, server-name

I'm installing a symfony project on `/var/www/`

And I have a special landing page stored here `/var/www/web/landingpage`

I want my visitors accessing `http://www.mydomain.com` to land on my landingpage and the ones accessing `http://www.mydomain.com/foo` to land on my symfony project.

I created 2 virtualhosts with different `ServerPath` and the landing page is working but not the symfony project.

Here is my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerPath /
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web/landingpage
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.com.error.log
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com sf.mydomain.com
    ServerPath /sf/

    DocumentRoot /var/www/web

    DirectoryIndex frontend.php

    <Directory /var/www/web>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride none

            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                    RewriteEngine On

                    # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
                    RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
                    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

                    # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    Alias /sf /var/www/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.sf.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.sf.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: my second Virtualhost without the first one and without `ServerPath` directive is working perfectly

The error I got in the browser:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /foo/ was not found on this server.

Comment: why don't you do these by routings in Symfony2?

Comment: The main problem is that I have actually 3 different languages: de, fr and es. So I got mydomain.fr, mydomain.de and mydomain.net. fr and de are working great. The only exception is for mydomain.net since I have to keep mydomain.net for corporate landing page and mydomain.net/es for the real es website.

Comment: morever, these apache2 configs are messed up. You are trying to define  two virtualhosts with same name and different DocumentRoot. And there are symfony1.x configs in it

Comment: Yes, I don't know how symfony2 got in the tag, I should have explain symfony1. But I'm not sure it is relevant here.

Comment: Ok, I have removed Symfony2 tag.

Comment: I will +1 @Ferhad to handle that using symfony. This is really easy. If you think it's not possible please describe why with scenario for the special case of .net (what should be redirect to what, what should **not** be redirected, etc ..)

Comment: Actually, I don't see how routing can solve my problem. 

Let say I have domain.fr and domain.de pointing on my homepage. 

Routing.yml would be "homepage: /"

How do you make an exception for es ? domain.net/ pointing somehere else and domain.net/es pointing to "homepage".